# Prevent call to static.anychart.com and logo.png loading

Tags: anychart

How can I deactivate the call to https://static.anychart.com/logo.png?

My license is activated and I use credits(false), but at this point the call is already gone.

How can I prevent the call?

Comment: Please, check if you create a stage instance on the page manually using an API call like this: `var stage = anychart.graphics.create('container');` and let us know about the result

Comment: This is exactly how we create the stages.

The first thing I do is the license call.
anychart.licenseKey("MY-KEY");
After that I create a chart with anychart.fromJson
On this chart I disable the credits with chart.credits(false)
then I create the stage as you describe with anychart.grphics.create and set it as container on my chart. After that I draw the chart. No credits are displayed, but it still makes a call to https://static.anychart.com/logo.png.

Comment: This call in some cases takes several seconds which significantly degrades the performance of our application!
If I look in the debugger where exactly the image is requested, the origin is the anychart.graphics.create.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading the `logo.png` while using the stage instance you can use the workaround below:

```
    var stage = anychart.graphics.create();
    stage.suspend();
    stage.credits().enabled(false);
    stage.container("container");
    stage.resume();
```